# How to make a label display multiple lines before the leading constraint of another label?

Tags: ios, uitableview, user-interface, constraints, uicollectionviewcell

I'm doing an assignment from a book for learning iOS development. The assignment requires that the name label at the upper left area of a table cell should be able to display multiple lines if the name is too long and it should not go beyond the leading constraint of the value label at the far right of the same cell like this:

[image: The desired effect]

Besides the other usual constraints, I added the trailing constraint to the name label, which is equal to the trailing constraint of the value label, like this:

[image: Name label.trailing = Value label.trailing]

And the run result is like the following:

[image: Name label text runs over value label text]

The name label text undesirably runs over the top of the value label text.

I've also tried to add a horizontal space between the name label and the value label, but the compiler reported a conflict of constraints. Would you please tell me what I should do to make it right?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First You need to set Your name label trailing constraint to your value label leading like as below

[image]

Then If you try to increase content of your name label it shows error like this

[image]

To Solve this error go to View Controller View hierarchy and change the priority of name label

[image]

[image]

Then You achieved...

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Silversky Technology, for your answer. I tried your method which almost worked except for the phenomenon that the value label was either squeezed into an ellipsis or simply pushed over the right margin. I solved the problem by tuning down the "Content Compression Resistance Priority" of the name label from 750 to 250. Now it's working all fine. However, I'd like to thank you for giving me the clue for a start.

Answer (score 1):

If you typed that correctly, then your problem is you set the trailing anchor of the name label equal to the trailing anchor of the value label. That would mean that the right edge of each label has to be equal. You don't want that. The system is probably breaking your constraint and making its own weird one instead which is causing the undesirable behavior.

Set the trailing anchor of the name label equal to the *leading* anchor of the value label minus some constant (whatever padding you want).

Programmatically you do something like this

```
nameButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
nameButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: valueButton.leadingAnchor, constant: -10)
```

If you must use storyboard, which I advise against in general, I think this or some other tutorial page will show you how. I don't know how to use storyboard very well at all.

https://www.raywenderlich.com/811496-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-getting-started

Comment: Thanks for your immediate reply. That's exactly the constraint which I'd wanted and tried to add, but which I hadn't found a way to add. Would please tell me how to add the constraint in the storyboard instead of in code? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you, Kyle Bums, for your answer. I tried the code for aligning the trailing constraint of the name label with the leading constraint of the value label plus a constant as padding. However, it didn't work out as expected. The result is the same as that in the answer provided by Silversky Technology above. I found out that tuning down the  "Content Compression Resistance Priority" of the name label from 750 to 250 did really help. But thank you for your help. You and Silversky Technology did provide me with the initial clue to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

tried this one, hoping the following is the result you required

[final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjYny.png)

in order to acquire this

1. first insert two labels in the cell as follows

[labels added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnfHW.png)

2. given top and leading constraints for the title label

[title label constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n51HQ.png)

3. in order to give constraints (Horizontal spacing) between title and the amount
   right click and hold in title label and drag to amount label. it will show a
   pop up window as follows

[horizontal spacing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/453I4.png)

once we select the horizontal spacing we have to change according to our need

in-order to change select title label then select ***size inspector*** from the
right window

then change the trailing space to the amount label

[updated value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H21bO.png)

now given constraints for title label

- leading
- top
- horizontal spacing to amount label (trailing)

once it given it will show error in the constraints since the amount label constraints are not given

next have to give constraints for amount label

- trailing
- width and size
- vertical position on the cell

[constraints for amount label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbwsP.png)

now try to input larger text values in title label

[look like one more step to complete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgOZj.png)

in order to get multiple line change the number of ***line*** property value of title label to ***0*** in attribute inspector

[final output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CISaC.png)

Comment: Thank you, @Chandramohan KP, for your patient help. I tried your approach, but unfortunately it didn't work on the Xcode 12.4 with iPhone 11 simulator. The result was that the value label disappeared as if it was pushed over to the right margin of the cell. I have no idea what was wrong, but thank you for your help anyway.